# I just want a lookup field on Lead for Queue

Tags: trigger, custom-field, lookup-filter

I tried to create a lookup field on Lead object for **Queue**.
but unable to find queue.
Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

The `Owner` (standard) field lets you select a Queue on Cases, Leads, Orders, Custom Objects, Service Contracts, and Knowledge Articles. but you can't do this using a custom `Lookup` field. A request for this feature is posted on the [Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brmk) and as of right now, is under review.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this

Comment: @dem Two off the top of my head: make use of the `Owner` field which is arguably the best way, second would be to store the `Queue` Id in a text field so you can reference it.